# How to perform masking with custom values or random values in apache kafka source connector and then unmasking the message in kafka sink connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

```
{
transforms=SSNMask,IPMask,PhoneMask 
transforms.SSNMask.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value
transforms.SSNMask.fields=ssn
}
```

transforms should have some additional property to using custom values or random values instead of null values.